# R multiple pie charts from count table?

Tags: r, pie-chart

If my data looks like this:

```
group <- c("A","B","C","D")
count1 <- c(1:4)
count2 <- c(2,2,3,4)
count3 <- c(4,3,2,1)
data <- cbind(group,count1,count2,count3)
```

how can I get pie charts of rows and of columns? That is, a single plot with 4 pie charts and one legend for the distribution of count variables within groups, and a plot with 3 pie charts for the distribution of groups within each count? Also, if theres a better way then pie charts to show this, I'd be happy for offers.

Comment: Your example data comes out as characters instead of numeric. Are you sure this is the structure you want? Also what have you tried? Currently you are asking for multiple things at once and it's not clear what you are strugglig with... generally we'd prefer bar plots to pie charts in most cases, because it's more difficult to read the order of values from pie charts

Comment: @dario the bar chart solution below works! The reason I wanted pie charts, though, is that in my data the groups are very different in size so I thought of showing relative frequency. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix example data, so it's numeric and not character (using `rbind` forces to matrix. A matrix can only hold a single data type, and R always uses the most general one in these cases, i.e. character):

```
group<-c("A","B","C","D")
count1<-c(1:4)
count2<-c(2,2,3,4)
count3<-c(4,3,2,1)
df <- data.frame(group,count1,count2,count3)
```

Suggested solution using `ggplot2` for plottig as well as `dplyr` and `tidyr` for restructuring data into long form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Alternativey we could use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`...

## Edit:

How to show relative percentages per `group` (using `ggplot2`, `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `scales`):

```
group<-c("A","B","C","D")
count1<-c(1:4)
count2<-c(2,2,3,4)
count3<-c(4,3,2,1)
df <- data.frame(group, count1, count2, count3)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-group) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(relFreq = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, relFreq, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  expand_limits(y=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: That works! The reason I wanted pie charts, though, is that in my data the groups are very different in size so I thought of showing relative frequency. How do I do that?

Comment: Relative frequencies (percentages) of what? Per group?

Comment: yes the relative count1, count2 and count3 within each of A,B,C,D